# Python convert list of large json objects to DF

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a list of objects to a pandas dataframe. The objects are large and complex, a sample one can be found **[here](https://pypi.org/pypi/pandas/json)**

The output should be a DF with 3 columns: info, releases, URLs - as per the json object linked above. I've tried pd.DataFrame and from_records, but I keep getting hit with errors. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pd.read_json() function?

Here's a link to the documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.json.read_json.html